# How do you convert 1 minute open-high-low-close data to another timeframe(fx: 5 minute, 1 hour) in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, currency, finance

I'm pretty new to Python and StackOverflow so bear with me if I make mistakes in this post.

I have a Pandas dataframe with 1 minute open, high, low, and close data, with time as the index, for a currency. How would I go about turning it into a dataframe with, for example, 5-minute open, high, low, close data, and make the timestamp fit too? Here is an example of the 1-minute data printed out:

```
                   ZARJPY_open  ZARJPY_high  ZARJPY_low  ZARJPY_close
time                                                            
201901011700        7.589        7.589       7.589         7.589
201901011701        7.590        7.590       7.590         7.590
201901011702        7.589        7.590       7.589         7.589
201901011703        7.590        7.593       7.590         7.593
201901011705        7.592        7.593       7.592         7.593
```

I would like to turn this into:

```
                  ZARJPY_open  ZARJPY_high  ZARJPY_low  ZARJPY_close
time                                                            
201901011700        7.589        7.593       7.589         7.593
201901011706                  -next 5 minutes-
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Edit: Time stamp is in YYYYMMDDHHmm (year, month, day, hour, minute) format

Comment: Welcome to SO. What's your time stamp format? How do you want to agg data after resampling? What's your logic?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Time format is YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm, what exactly do you mean by agg?

Comment: I mean how do you exactly obtained the values `7.589        7.593       7.589         7.593` for `201901011700`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Open is the first price in the timeframe, high is the highest price, low is the lowest price, close is the last price before a new timeframe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a 5-minute grouper object:

```
# parse the time. 
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format="%Y%m%d%H%M")

#make the time the index. 
df = df.set_index("time")

# group in 5-minute chunks. 
t = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5Min')).agg({"ZARJPY_open": "first", 
                                             "ZARJPY_close": "last", 
                                             "ZARJPY_low": "min", 
                                             "ZARJPY_high": "max"})
t.columns = ["open", "close", "low", "high"]
print(t)
```

The result is:

```
                      open  close    low   high
time                                           
2019-01-01 17:00:00  7.589  7.593  7.589  7.593
2019-01-01 17:05:00  7.592  7.593  7.592  7.593
```

Comment: I don't know if it's too much to ask, but how do you convert your index from type Int64 to a time index. The index is formatted like a timestamp (YYYYMMDDHHmm), the type is just Int64 instead of a timestamp format. (I found a solution for converting Unix time, but can't find anything for this)

Comment: Added to the code. If this answers your question, could you please accept it as an answer for future generations?

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly :D. I've marked your answer as correct!

Comment: thank you for the answer, it helped me as well

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this. Short, sweet, precise solution!