# How to aggregate 2-day bars historical stock data using yfinance in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

I am using the code in the answer provided in the link below to aggregate the daily prices to 2-day period (freq='2B'); however, the datestamp shows the starting date of the aggregation period.  Is it possible to show the result stamped with the last date of the period?

example: if aggregating over Jan 16th and 17th, the datestamp would show 2023-01-17

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74775358/13415270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pd.Grouper()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) supports a `convention` parameter. You could set this param to `"e"` or `"end"`. `convention` requires to have a period index. Thus, you should set the index first. Putting it all together:

```py
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

df = yf.download("AAPL", period="2y", interval="1h")

# set period index
df.index = df.index.to_period(freq="2B")
# use convention
df_agg = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="2B", convention="end")).agg(
    {"Open": "first", "High": "max", "Low": "min", "Close": "last", "Adj Close": "last"}
)
df_agg.head()
```

**Output:**

```
    Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close
Datetime                    
2021-01-22  133.863998  139.850006  133.789993  138.969894  138.969894
2021-01-26  143.222702  145.080002  136.539993  143.184998  143.184998
2021-01-28  143.429993  144.300003  136.699997  137.089996  137.089996
2021-02-01  136.179993  136.729996  130.210007  134.110001  134.110001
2021-02-03  135.729996  136.309998  133.610001  133.904999  133.904999
```